# Can the BSON or JSON crate automatically transform an unsigned number in a string to a floating number when it finds one?

Tags: json, rust, bson

I have a string that I would like to transform to BSON. It works except when my body contains an attribute with a number in it. I get the error:

> parsing was unsuccessful BSON does not support unsigned type

I've found that I should be able to create a struct that implements `Serialize` and `Deserialize` to resolve my issue, but I don't know what is in the body of my struct (and it can change with lot of possibility).

```rust
let bson_string = r#"{ "user-agent": "blablabla", "userid": "XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX", "session": { "XXXXXXX": [{ "body": {"type":"input","payload":{"id":"email","length":1},"url":"https://blablabla.com/paiement/offres/pack-simple/Y8s2cdZ1vU/auth"}, "origin": "https://blablabla.com" }] } }"#;

let json: Value = match serde_json::from_str(&bson_string){
    Ok(val) => val,
    Err(err) => {
        println!("from_str err: {:?}", err);
        serde_json::Value::Null
    }
};
let v = match mongodb::to_bson(&json) {
    Ok(val) => val,
    Err(err) => {
        println!("to_bson err: {:?}", err);
        mongodb::Bson::Null
    }
};
v
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to reduce your JSON string to a single object with a single field that demonstrates the problem? Right now, it's difficult to see exactly what it is you are asking about.

Comment: You can replace it by r#"{ "length":1 }"# but i would keep the big one for demonstrate that the issue can't be resolved with a struct with serialize/deserialize